# Matlab, finding common values in two array

Tags: arrays, matlab, find

I want to find common values in two arrays(For example if A=[1 2 3 4 5 6] and B=[9 8 7 6 3 1 2] the result is ans=[1 2 3 6]).Is there any method without using loop?

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

use `intersect(A,B)` to get the answer.

Another option is to use `ismember`, for example `A(ismember(A,B))`.